Windows - redirect stdout and stderr output to a file avoiding unsync
Following answer from this question I've found that using dir > a.txt 2>&1 to output stdout and stderr to a file might be unreliable as stdout and stderr appear to get unsynced sometimes. The result in the file differs from what I see when running the command directly in the console — e.g. stderr output can appear before stdout or after, seemingly at random.
Is there a more reliable way to redirect both outputs to a file on Windows without editing the executed program itself? It seems the most reliable way is to just ctrl-shift-a and copy the output but it can be impractical.
Simple way to reproduce this is to run the following command:
py -c "for i in range(5, -1, -1): print(1/i)" > out.txt 2>&1

Resulting out.txt:
Traceback (most recent call last):
0.2
0.25
0.3333333333333333
0.5
1.0
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

I've found if it's just a python script then running using -u argument helps: py -u -c "for i in range(5, -1, -1): print(1/i)" > out.txt 2>&1 (it "forces the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered. This option has no effect on the stdin stream."). But it still inconsistent, if you try to run the same command multiple times - you'll see that output can be different.

PS This question is a repost of the same question from stackoverflow since it was closed because it wasn't about "a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers.". There is some information in the previous question comments section - there are some arguments why there could be no general solution for this but I'm still looking for workarounds.
